# Does android kill singleton in order to free memory?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, singleton

I've got a very weird problem and is difficult to describe so please read carefully the assumptions before the answer to avoid jumping into something I already know isn't

1 - I've got an android app which login from my server
2 - after a successful login I instantiate a ***Singleton API*** which will be shared across the activities in order to make the requests to the server
3 - Isn't possible to use the app without login
4 - in my login activity I have a very clean condition

```
if(APIFacade.getInstance() != null){
startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

}else {/*error handling*/}
```

5 - there is just one call to `startActivity` method in the whole `LoginActivity`class so isn't possible to start `MainActivity` without check if the facade is null
6 - it isn't possible to set `APIFacade.INSTANCE` to `null` after instantiating it

But even with all these conditions sometimes users get `NullPointerException` on `MainActivity` when the app tries to make the first call to API after login

`String url = APIFacade.getInstance().getProfilePicUrl(); //throws nullpointerexception on 5% of the times`

APIFacade class is like this:

```
public class APIFacade {
 private static APIFacade INSTANCE = null;

  @WorkerThread
    public APIFacade(Object i, final boolean preLoad) {
        INSTANCE = this;
//other stuff
}

  public static APIFacade getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I'm not able to reproduce the problem in the development environment so I just know it happens due to the crashlytics dashboard on firebase...

I believe my code has no leak to lead this situation, so the only theory I got is: Android is *cleaning* some variables from memory when my app goes background...

I know android naturally does it for activities, but singletons?
and if yes what can I do to solve it?

Comment: What kind of singleton are you using?

Comment: `Application.onCreate()` is called always when the app comes to foreground, so try to initialize the `INSTANCE` there .

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the answer myself thanks to a great article: https://medium.com/@davethomas_9528/please-dont-use-singletons-to-persist-state-on-android-7bac9bc78b29

Briefly:
Everybody says that singleston on android are attached to the application life, so will only be released if the application is killed

THIS IS TRUE

what you dont hear, is that the application can be killed by the SO without user interaction (to release memory for foreground apps) and in this scenario when the user tries to come back to your app it will restart from the last used activity and not from the launcher activity.